# What is the reason of try-catch-rethrow without additional processing in catch block?

Tags: c#, .net, try-catch

Sometimes i meet the following construction exploring ServiceStack's code base:

```
try
{
   ...
}
catch (Exception)
{
   throw;
}
```

In my oppinion this construction does nothing. What is the possible reason of doing this?

Comment: Seems a bit like a defensive programming mechanic..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right - it's generally pointless. I have seen people include it so that they can put a break point on the `throw` line (so they get to see when an exception is thrown, even if they're not breaking on exceptions in general). Unfortunately it often gets left in there after the debugging session has finished.

If you encounter this within a code base you control, I suggest you remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Last time I stumbled over such a construct I asked the author why. Why I was particulary curious was that he did not do this all willy nilly but only in a few places.

His response came with the 'let exceptions be exceptional' which I guess he must have picked up from Eric Lippert where he added that most of his methods would/(should) never throw where in some places his code could throw. By adding the try/catch/throw he was communicating to maintainers that he had recognized that this could happen.

Naturally we try to write code that does not blow up at all. For example by using Code Contracts the number of methods that actually can throw is reduced dramatically.